# Table cell reusing button in different section iOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, cell, reusability

i have created `UITableView` with 4 section with dynamic numbers of rows, i customized the cell and added button to very cell, buttons are reusing in different section .

**My code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath



 {



     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)


     {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      }


     self.buttonMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [ self.buttonMe setFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    self.buttonMe.tag=i;

    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])

    [ self.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    else

    [ self.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [ self.buttonMe addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: self.buttonMe];

    cell.textLabel.text=@"itsFine";
//"i", i created for assigning the unique tag for created button every time
    i++;

    return cell;

}
```

please give me proper solution with reason of why its happening
thanks

Comment: You have not customized the cell. `ButtonMe` should be part of custom cell and `cell.buttonMe` is what should be changed, what you are doing is reusing the instance variable of your main class.

Comment: i added custom button as subView of cell.contentView,

Comment: what please clear this your line what you are doing is reusing the instance variable of your main class

Comment: self.buttonMe is being added to cell everytime. What you can instead do is create a custom cell and have a variable buttonMe and access it via cell.buttonMe. That way you won't have issues with cell reuse.

Comment: pls praveen help me, how acheive this pls pls pls

Comment: I have added my answer, you can take a look @Kritika Bansal.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Its untested, not compiled code just to give you an idea.

Ok i will try to outline the way to create a custom uitableview cell

```
@interface MyCustomCell  : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton * buttonMe

@end
```

The implementation will have the following

```
@implementation MyCustomCell 
@synthesize buttonMe;

- (UIButton *) buttonMe {
     if(!buttonMe){
      buttonMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [buttonMe setFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
     }
return buttonMe;
}

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (( self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] )) {
     [self addSubView:self.buttonMe];
      }
 }

@end
```

Next you can modify your code as follows:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          }
        [cell.buttonMe setFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
        cell.buttonMe.tag=i;

        if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"]){
        [cell.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
        else{
        [cell.buttonMe setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
        cell.textLabel.text=@"itsFine";
        i++;

        return cell;
```

Finally add the button click handler in your custom class.

Answer (score -1):

Not clear from your question what you are trying to ask. If I am not mistaking than you have 4 section & each of them have some rows(cell) inside & every row has check & uncheck button. You are tagging the button so that you can get the index of that button to do some action.

Now, Remember `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will get called every time you scroll your tableview either upwards or downwards. So the "i" will get increment every time you scroll your tableview.

So if you have 10 rows & you thiks that you have set i = 0 to 9 for every row. But when you scroll every time "i" will get incremented. And hence you might not able to use the tag value further in your code.

better is to use `indexPath.row` of tableview. this will be unique for every row.

now modify your code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     if (cell == nil)
     {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        /*Reusing you button*/
        [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"itsFine";
      }
      myButton.tag = indexPath.row; // Should not use i at here

    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
       [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
       [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i taken ur point but, problem as it is, as loading the view its not showing button but when i scroll it then its coming , secondly, when i select first row of section 0 than all section firs row get selected, resolve it please

Comment: yes, bcoz you are using the same button object. hence when you select one button all button gets selected. I am editing mu previous answer & see if it works.

Comment: myButton has been added when cell is nil, what happens when the cells start getting reused. There are lot of issues here.